# HTML td'width will be changed after a long input value

Tags: html

I got this problem:

an input tag in td tag,
when input value is been set too long,
the td's width will change unexpected!

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: give a certain width to input (e.g. style="width:100px") so the value will not expand input size.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your CSS.

```
 input { width:100px;}
```